# Unsplit lines seperated by a small gap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, pipe-network

I have a set of polylines that represent fire hydrant laterals and many/all of them are in two peices one from the main to a valve on that line and one from the valve to the hydrant.  Some have small gaps at where the valve is located which causes them to not unsplit when I run that command.

I know functions like intersect have a search radius, is there something similar to this for the unsplit lines tool?  Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the unsplit line tool, you can also use a tolerance if you go to the environment settings of your tool > XY resolution or tolerance. The tolerance will make closeby points coincident.

You can also clean up the data before you use unsplit line. There are two major tools to do that :

- [snap](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001v00000007000000.htm) this tool works in an edit session. You can define the snapping environment to "ends" to make sure that  you snap the right features. See [here](http://www.esri.com/news/arcwatch/0412/use-the-snap-geoprocessing-tool-to-automate-editing.html) for more details
- [extend](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001v00000004000000.htm) (extending lines until they intersect ) will not work if your lines are parallel. May cause some artefact if the intersection of the two extended lines is on one of the two lines (then you have a dangle that needs to be trimmed)
- [integrate](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000002s000000) (moving ALL vertices that are close to each other based on a tolerance) Be carefull because other points than the ends could also move.

Comment: Thank you,  I will look into the environment settings next time I am at my station with arcgis and give you an update on how succesfull I was.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking this may be a two-step process?

Use the "Extend Line" tool to extend the lines to the next feature (this helps clean up issues with features created without snapping), then run your Unsplit tool.